# What is the name of doors that open everywhere by being pushed on in only one part?

Tags: door

I want to design a kind of contemporary door that I've seen before where it opens by splitting down the middle, and if you push on only one half of the door, the other half still opens at the same speed. Is there a name for this kind of door?

Comment: Are you able to sketch something to show us what you mean?

Comment: If I understand what you mean correctly you just need to have doors that overlap in some way and have a push-to-open mechanism on each, so you press on one door and it pushes both doors in and they pop open as a pair (as long as you press on the correct door). There are various names for these mechanisms including push latches and push-botton catches.

Comment: Are you perhaps referring to an [evolution door](http://www.themethodcase.com/klemens-torgglers-rotating-evolution-door/)?

Comment: @CharlieKilian, that seems much more likely to be what the OP meant. Nice catch!

Comment: An evolution door is not quite what I meant, the way in which it opens is much simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for a set of connected Pivot Doors like this.

Your hinge mechanisms need to be connected so as one moves, the other matches.

[image: Pivot Doors]

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, it is a motorized cable door, but could easily be adapted to use without the motor.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q8If4YSlhfY

If that is not it, here is a pretty extensive list of different door mechanisms, they are from a youtuber whom does a lot of CAD mechanisms, and has a fondness for doors. If what you are looking for is not on here, you can walk away with some ideas at the least.
https://www.youtube.com/user/thang010146/search?query=door

Comment: It's difficult for this Q but as a rule try to avoid link-only Answers. From the [Help Center](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/help), *Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.*

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to Accordion doors like the ones [here](http://house-ideas.org/10-accordian-doors-ease-and-beauty.html)?

[image]